# PHPMailer and AddEmbeddedImage causes blank mail content

Tags: php, phpmailer

Whenever I try to embed an image, GMail will show a blank content instead of the HTML message.

Here is the code:

```
$body = file_get_contents($filesDir . '/emails/wbd.html');
$mail = new \PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = $c['config']['mail.params']['auth'];
$mail->SMTPSecure = $c['config']['mail.params']['secure'];
$mail->Host = $c['config']['mail.params']['host'];
$mail->Port = $c['config']['mail.params']['port'];
$mail->Username = $c['config']['mail.params']['user'];
$mail->Password = $c['config']['mail.params']['password'];
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SetFrom('example@gmail.com', 'Some name');
$mail->Subject = 'Some subject';
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($filesDir . '/emails/img/community-i.png', 'community-i', 'community-i.png');
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->Send();
```

If I'd remove the function call to *AddEmbeddedImage*, then the HTML mail is sent.
The path to the image *$filesDir . '/emails/img/community-i.png'* is correct as the function *AddEmbeddedImage* returns true (and an incorrect path will show the HTML message).

I also try just this:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($filesDir . '/emails/img/community-i.png', 'community-i');
$mail->Body = 'Embedded Image: <img alt="PHPMailer" src="cid:community-i"> Here is an image!';
```

But same issue, blank content (and if I comment *AddEmbeddedImage* function call, the content will show up and as expected instead of the image, the alt tag appears).

I tested on Gmail, Yahoo and Hotmail and have the same problem for all the addresses.

Comment: what happens with another address email addresses? is the image used in the email content?

Comment: what do you mean "with address email addresses" ?

Comment: sorry, send it to a non gmail address.

Comment: same issue with Hotmail and Yahoo (when I comment the AddEmbeddedImage function, it works and image is replaced by its ALT text).

Comment: next guess, try the full server path to the image

Comment: I tried from localhost, and same problem.
If I echo the path to the file, it's like "C:\Data\websites\wbd/emails/img/community-i.png"

Comment: I tried with .jpg but again same problem. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make SURE that your PHPMailer library is up-to-date!